# Win 7 Pro.. Prints from Note pad ok.. Any other Application sends 2 print files to print spooler

Tags: printing

Win 7 Pro 
Dell computer with HP1505 printer connected to USB port.
Prints from note pad
When trying to print from Explorer or any other application 2 files show up in the print spooler.
1st file contains no information 0 file size, 2nd file contains print job . 
By deleting the first file, the job prints...
Printer is also network shared and has no problem printing jobs sent from other PC's connected to the network
Duplicate print jobs only occuries when trying to print from the local PC